# GeoServer WCS geotiff style not loading in ArcMAP

Tags: geoserver, wcs

I have published a GeoTIFF file using GeoServer's (2.4.5) WCS service.

I also defined a colormap style on GeoServer.  I know the style works, because, when I load the map through WMS the colormap is there and the legend image is also generated.

But when I try to load it into ArcMAP or QGis using WCS, I just get a stretched gray scale.

Opening the same GeoTIFF file directly from the catalog in arcmap, lets me calculate the statistics and histogram, and then I can define and edit a colormap for that layer, but this option to calculate the statistics for the WCS raster is not available.

I also tried to create a classified or unique value colormap in the symbology tab at the properties dialog, but those options are not available for the WCS, only for the file opened directly.

How can I make ArcMap take into account the style information I created using GeoServer or, alternatively, how can I make ArcMap let me create and use a classified colormap for this WCS raster.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: There is no GeoServer 2.5.5 and nor is there likely to be one. I guess you mean 2.4.5?

Comment: yes sorry, I ment 2.4.5

Comment: WCS is designed to return the data not the portrayal which is what you see in a WMS - so it seems to be working as designed.

Comment: A GeoServer WCS service can return a colour image, but so far it doesn't look like you have tested your service to see if your style is applied correctly.  Try a direct WCS GetCoverage request in your browser (WCS 2.0.1 is probably the simplest sytax) like: http://localhost/geoserver-2.5/OneGDev/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&CoverageId=OneGDev__GTR_NRTH_SEA_MCoL&request=GetCoverage&format=image/png&

Answer (score 2):

According to what can be read from ArcGIS` help site ([Adding a WCS service to ArcMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sp0000000z000000)), there is no statistical information in the WCS layer that ArcMap can use to provide renderers other than stretched and discrete for WCS raster display.  A WCS layer is different from a file raster layer in this respect.

WMS layers, however, can include style information, which is set up at the map server level.